# Does "I keep/raise hens in my backyard" imply the hens are my pets / the hens are my meat?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Someone says:

"I keep hens in my backyard" suggests that you have hens as pets or for personal enjoyment. It implies that you are responsible for their care and well-being.

"I raise hens in my backyard" implies a more purposeful and active involvement in the process of raising hens. It suggests that you are intentionally involved in breeding, hatching, or raising the hens, possibly for specific purposes such as egg production or meat.

**Is it true? or are they the same?**

Comment: keeping and raising can be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

To "raise" hens (or anything) does imply that you are "growing" them from young to old. You would probably not use that word  if you bought fully-grown hens. Most people "raise" hens for eggs or for sale, but it isn't necessary.

To "keep" hens merely implies that you have hens in your backyard, and that you are keeping them there deliberately (i.e. they haven't wandered in by accident). You might also be "raising" them as above. You might be buying mature hens. You might be keeping them for pleasure or profit, for eggs or meat, as pets, or for some other reason.

Exactly the same applies to dogs, for example. If you "keep" dogs then you have some dogs - they might be pets, guard dogs, or working dogs. If you "raise" dogs then you acquire them as puppies (or breed them) and let them grow. Probably you are breeding them so you can sell them to others, but not necessarily.